# Highcharts not aligning to ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

One more highcharts question:

I can't seem to get this to line up with the ticks

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/gTQ75/1/

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Testing Phase'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Phase'],
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {

                    categories: ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3', 'Option4', 'Option5', 'Option6', 'Option7', 'Option8', 'Option9', 'Option10', 'Option11', 'Option12', 'Option13', 'Option14'],
        labels: {
            rotation: 45,
        y:40  
        },
                    min: 0,
                    max: 13,
                    endOnTick: false,
                    startOnTick: false,
                    tickInterval: 1,
```

I have changed endOnTick and startOnTick to true but I still get the same results.
I know I am close but I'm just not getting it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the option you are looking for is [tickMarkPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickmarkPlacement).  Set it to `on`:

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gTQ75/3/).

```
yAxis: {
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on', 
    // other options here
}
```